# GO to onother task with butten clicked

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have an `entry_TextChanged` event handler and a button.

How can I say if this button clicked go to that `entry_TextChanged` handler again?

```
private bool save = false;

private void entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (save == true)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}

private void goto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    save = true;

    // GO and do the entry texchanged??
}
```

Comment: Create a routine, something like `SaveData()` and have each event call that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just call it the same as any other function `entry_TextChanged(null, null)` or any other values that you want to send to the function

```
    private void goto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        save = true;

        entry_TextChanged(null, null)
    }
```

Comment: tanks a lot @styx. Can u help me out with my other question bro?